# “We can't save the customer” Alert on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-address

In Magento 2, on the `registration.HTML file, I have enabled the address fields.
But when I try to create or register a new customer, it shows "We can't save the customer".

Can anyone tell me where I am lacking?

It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Hi I am also facing the same error in Magento 2.3.0 If I am changing the PHP Versiom some other things are being unfuctional. Please help if anyone knows

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157424)

Answer (score 20):

You most probably have an error somewhere.
In order to find out what the problem is you can add this code.

```
$this->messageManager->addException($e, $e->getMessage());
```

Instead of the line

```
$this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t save the customer.'));
```

in `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost::execute()`.
This should give you the exception message on the screen and you will have a place to start.

Comment: The file is `vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php`

Comment: Better yet, you can just comment out all of the try/cache blocks

Comment: @marius i have used your above code which you have mentioned it returns "Email must be a valid email address" How to fix this? https://prnt.sc/nptom5  could you please suggest

Comment: @NagarajuKasa Maybe for some reason the email does not get sent from your form.

Comment: Recently upgraded from magento2.2.3 CE to magento2.3.1 CE after upgraded we are getting this issue. is there any alternative way to fix this

Comment: Yes, it gives me an exact error that why does it occur.

Comment: For me, it shows Content must be string or resource; received "Magento\Framework\Phrase"

Can you help me how to solve this?
I migrated from m1 to m2.3

Answer (score 1):

I had this error using Magento 2.3, I simply moved down from PHP 7.2 to 7.1 and problem fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This error can be realted to **PHP compatibility** :

- For `Magento 2.3` : `PHP 7.1`
- For `Magento 2.2` : `PHP 7.1` or `PHP 7.0`
- For `Magento 2.1` : `PHP 7.1`, `PHP 7.0` or `PHP 5.6`
- For `Magento 2.0` : `PHP 7.0`, `PHP 5.6` or `PHP 5.5`

Check your PHP version, and upgrade or downgrade PHP if needed.

**You will never make Magento 2 works fine without the good version of PHP**

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using some commands:

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
sudo chmod 777 -R generated
sudo chmod 777 -R var
sudo bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 0):

This happening because of validation file in `vendor\magento\framework\File\Uploader` and in this function

```
 private function _setUploadFileId($fileId)
    {
        if (is_array($fileId)) {
            $this->validateFileId($fileId);
            $this->_uploadType = self::MULTIPLE_STYLE;
            $this->_file = $fileId;
        }
```

comment this following line in the above function:

```
// $this->validateFileId($fileId);
```

We can need to override the above function using
the following steps:
We can override using preference.

1. Create di.xml

   ```
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="vendor\magento\framework\File\Uploader" type="NameSpace\Customer\Framework\File\Uploader" />
   ```
2. Create class php file
   In the given path put your fle `NameSpace\Customer\Framework\File\Uploader`

Answer (score 0):

In our case, in Magento 2.4.5-p2, the problem was solved by configuring the SMTP service, done that, problem solved.