# Magento 2 Create New Customer Account gives `We can't save the customer.` error while creating new customer account in frontend

Tags: magento2, customer-account, register, frontend-error

I am facing some issue while I am adding new customer account from frontend. When I fill the details of Create New Customer Account Form and submit the form then I got the error `We can't save the customer.` in frontend.
[image]

And when I check for the customer record in admin panel under CUSTOMERS > All Customers. The customer record has been added to my records in admin panel.
[image]

Then I followed [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114469/we-cant-save-the-customer-alert-on-magento-2), and added `$this->messageManager->addException($e, $e->getMessage());` to trace out the issue and it only shows the error:

> Invalid argument

Is there any issue related to customer attribute? How can i debug and fix this issue?

----- Update -----

I checked `system.log`, It shows this error:

> main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Invalid argument
>
> Trace: #0 /var/www/html/mydomain.com/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(167): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_connect('tcp://57:587')

Comment: copy error from exception.log and update this answer.

Comment: Hi @SohelRana, I had updated my question.